# isAuthenticated always false using Javascript express and passport

Tags: javascript, middleware

I am trying to add isLoggedIn middleware that uses isAuthenticated to my small app but seems that it is not working. 
By removing the middleware, the Login page works fine and redirects, but if I add it to the admin page(where the login redirects), the `console.log(isAuthenticated())` is always **false**.

It seems that something happens with the credentials after adding the middleare and they cannot be checked. 
I bet it is something tiny but after hours I couldn't figure it out.
The code of the app.js is the one below:

```
const express=require("express");
const expressSanitizer=require("express-sanitizer");
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const passport    = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const Caruser=require("./models/caruser");
const Carcheck=require("./models/carcheck");


let app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

//**********************
//connecting with the Car Check DB
//**********************
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/car_check_app", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to Car Check DB!'))
  .catch(error => console.log(error.message)); 

  app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret:"secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Caruser.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(Carcheck.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Carcheck.deserializeUser());
passport.serializeUser(Caruser.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Caruser.deserializeUser());

//**********************
//Routes
//**********************

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.send("Hi there!");
});

//LOGIN ROUTE
app.get("/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("login");
});

//LOGIN LOGIC
app.post("/login",passport.authenticate("local",{
    successRedirect: "/admin",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}), function(req, res){
});


//Admin Page
app.get("/admin",isLoggedIn, (req, res)=>{
    Carcheck.find({}).sort({created: -1}).exec( function(err,allentries){    
        if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    res.render("index", {CarchechObj:allentries}); 
                }
    });
});

//Drivers Page
app.get("/drivers", (req, res)=>{
    Caruser.find({}, function(err,allentries){    
        if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    res.render("drivers", {CaruserObj:allentries}); 
                }
    });
});

//Add Driver Page
app.get("/newdriver", function(req, res){
    res.render("newdriver");
});

//Create New Driver
app.post("/newdriver", function(req, res){
    var newDriver = new Caruser({
        username: req.body.username,
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
        role: req.body.role
    });
    Caruser.register(new Caruser(newDriver),req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.render("newdriver");
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
            res.redirect("/drivers"); 
        });
        
        });
});

//Delete Existing Driver
app.delete("/drivers/:id",function(req, res){
    Caruser.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err,deletedDriver){
        if (err) {
            res.redirect("/drivers");
        } else {
                    res.redirect("/drivers/");
                }
    });
});


//car inspection page
app.get("/car-inspection", function(req, res){
    res.render("car-inspection");
});

//car inspection filled
app.get("/car-inspection/:id", function(req, res){   
    Carcheck.findById(req.params.id).exec(function (err,foundCarInspection){   
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("car-inspected-show",{CarchechObj:foundCarInspection});        
        }
    });    
});

//car inspection checked by the admin
app.put("/car-inspection/:id", function(req, res){
    // find and update the correct car-inspection
    Carcheck.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {checked:"yes"}, function(err, checkedInspection){
       if(err){
           res.redirect("/car-inspection/"+req.params.id);
       } else {
           //redirect to the admin page
           res.redirect("/admin");
       }
    });
});

app.post("/car-inspection", (req, res)=>{
    var carPlate =req.sanitize( req.body.carPlate) 
    var carModel =req.sanitize( req.body.carModel)
    var carMiles =req.sanitize( req.body.carMiles)
    var tyrePressure =req.sanitize( req.body.tyrePressure)
    var tyrePressureNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.tyrePressureNotes )
    var fluids =req.sanitize( req.body.fluids)
    var fluidsNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.fluidsNotes)
    var damageVisual =req.sanitize( req.body.damageVisual)
    var damageVisualNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.damageVisualNotes)
    var cleaned =req.sanitize( req.body.cleaned)
    var cleanedNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.cleanedNotes)
    var windscreen =req.sanitize( req.body.windscreen)
    var windscreenNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.windscreenNotes)
    var horn =req.sanitize( req.body.horn)
    var hornNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.hornNotes)
    var lights =req.sanitize( req.body.lights)
    var lightsNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.lightsNotes)
    var sparetyre =req.sanitize( req.body.sparetyre)
    var sparetyreNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.sparetyreNotes)
    var brakes =req.sanitize( req.body.brakes)
    var brakesNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.brakesNotes)
    var tyreDepth =req.sanitize( req.body.tyreDepth)
    var tyreDepthNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.tyreDepthNotes)
    var mirrors =req.sanitize( req.body.mirrors)
    var mirrorsNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.mirrorsNotes)
    var seats =req.sanitize( req.body.seats)
    var seatsNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.seatsNotes)
    var wipers =req.sanitize( req.body.wipers)
    var wipersNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.wipersNotes)
    var warninglights =req.sanitize( req.body.warninglights)
    var warninglightsNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.warninglightsNotes)
    var steeringwheel =req.sanitize( req.body.steeringwheel)
    var steeringwheelNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.steeringwheelNotes)
    var battery =req.sanitize( req.body.battery)
    var batteryNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.batteryNotes)
    var leaks =req.sanitize( req.body.leaks)
    var leaksNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.leaksNotes)
    var doors =req.sanitize( req.body.doors)
    var doorsNotes =req.sanitize( req.body.doorsNotes)
    var agreement =req.sanitize( req.body.agreement)
    var created =req.sanitize( req.body.created)


    var newCarcheck={
        carPlate:carPlate,
        carModel:carModel, 
        carMiles:carMiles,
        tyrePressure:tyrePressure,
        tyrePressureNotes:tyrePressureNotes, 
        fluidsNotes:fluidsNotes,
        fluids:fluids,
        damageVisual:damageVisual, 
        damageVisualNotes:damageVisualNotes,
        cleaned:cleaned,
        cleanedNotes:cleanedNotes, 
        windscreen:windscreen,
        windscreenNotes:windscreenNotes,
        horn:horn,
        hornNotes:hornNotes,
        lights:lights,
        lightsNotes:lightsNotes,
        sparetyre:sparetyre,
        sparetyreNotes:sparetyreNotes,
        brakes:brakes,
        brakesNotes:brakesNotes,
        tyreDepth:tyreDepth,
        tyreDepthNotes:tyreDepthNotes,
        mirrors:mirrors,
        mirrorsNotes:mirrorsNotes,
        seats:seats,
        seatsNotes:seatsNotes,
        wipers:wipers,
        wipersNotes:wipersNotes,
        warninglights:warninglights,
        warninglightsNotes:warninglightsNotes,
        steeringwheel:steeringwheel,
        steeringwheelNotes:steeringwheelNotes,
        battery:battery,
        batteryNotes:batteryNotes,
        leaks:leaks,
        leaksNotes:leaksNotes,
        doors:doors,
        doorsNotes:doorsNotes,
        agreement:agreement,
        created:created
    } 
        Carcheck.create(newCarcheck, function(err,newEntry){ 
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                //redirect  to thank you page
                res.redirect("/checkadded");
            }
        });    
});

//check added page
app.get("/checkadded", function(req, res){
    res.render("checkadded");
});

//Logout
app.get("/logout", function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/login");
})


//Middleware
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect("/login");
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.ID, function()
{
    console.log("Server Started");
});
```

The caruser schema is this:

```
//**********************
//Creating Car User Schema to add it to car_check_app
//**********************

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose=require("passport-local-mongoose");

var carUserSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    role: String,
    password: String
  });
  
carUserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
//Creating Car Check Model
module.exports=mongoose.model("Caruser",carUserSchema);
```

I would really apreciate any help as it seems I have stuck here without any clue what to do.

Comment: I think you should pass the port number when you connect (`mongodb://localhost:27017/car_check_app`) that might be the issue

Comment: The think is that the whole program works fine if you don't add the middleware at the admin route. 10 letters make the login not working.

Comment: Could you try `{ resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true }` with this config for session?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh It didnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why isAuthenticated was not working and was giving always false.
Serialize/deserialize should only be used to the schemas that authentication should apply. I was using it to all the schemas I created and thus it was giving the false even if login credentials were correct.